# Clausura dentro de un bucle

Tags: javascript, bucles, sintaxis, clausuras

Tengo el siguiente código, no entiendo el resultado:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      
 funcs[i] = function() {          
  console.log("el valor: " + i); 
 };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
 funcs[j]();                     
}
```

Debería ser la salida `0`, `1` y `2`, pero en lugar de eso es: `3`, `3` y `3`.

¿Cuál es la explicación a esto?

Comment: La solución sería usar [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) en `for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución sería usar [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) en `for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)`, como se muestra en este código:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      
  funcs[i] = function() {          
    console.log("el valor: " + i); 
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                     
}
```

Si no me equivoco, esto se debe al ámbito de `var` y `let`. El ámbito de `var` es la función en la que se encuentra (y si no está dentro de una función, como era tu caso, es una variable global), mientras que el ámbito de `let` es el bloque en el que se define (tras el cambio, sólo el bucle `for`).

Con `var`, cuando se llama a las funciones de `funcs[]`, existe una variable global `i` que tiene el valor 3, por lo que ese es el valor que se devuelve en la consola. Mientras que si usas `let`, entonces no existe variable global `i` sólo el valor "local" de `i` cuando se creó la función y se devuelve lo que esperas.

Answer (score 5):

Como indica *@AlvaroMontoro*, el problema es debido al *alcance (scope)*, `let` define variables disponibles dentro del bloque de código inmediatamente superior mientras que `var` define una variable en el *alcance* de la función inmediatamente superior. Con `let` estás definiendo la variable dentro del bloque de código del `for` mientras que con `var` la defines dentro del alcance de la función donde está el código, o global si no está dentro de una función.

La solución de *AlvaroMontoro* funciona con *ES6* pero si quieres hacerlo en versiones anteriores debes crear un nuevo *scope* por cada iteración y la única manera de hacerlo es creando una función que cree un nuevo *scope* en la iteración del `for`, de esta manera:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   
 funcs.push((function(valor) {     
  return function() {
   console.log("el valor es: " + valor); 
  }
 })(i));
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
 funcs[j]();                     
}
```

Así es compatible en *ES5*.